# Use single SLD file to style multiple layers

Tags: geoserver

Is it possible in GeoServer to create a single SLD file that defines the styles for multiple layers? I created a single SLD with multiple NamedLayer elements with a Name element corresponding to each layer but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you share your interest in doing this.  In practice, I've found the 1 style >> 1 SLD to be helpful in organizing the styles.

Comment: We would like to create a master SLD that would have all the default styles in it to make it easier to do the initial setup of a client installation.